# How to change icon size?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using primereact and according to [there website this is how they change there icon size.](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/primeicons.xhtml)

However this doesn't work in jsx as it won't let you directly reference style without it being an object.

**Are there any workarounds to this?**

**EDIT: Code for Button where icon is nested in below:**

```
<Button 
  label="" 
  icon="pi pi-cog"   
  className="cogIcon"  
  onClick={(e) => this.setState({visibleRight:true})} 
  style={{marginTop:'.25em', marginRight:'.25em'} } 
/>
```

Comment: Can you provide some minimum reproducible code?

Comment: just added it.-

Comment: Did you try `style={{marginTop: '.25em', marginRight: '.25em', fontSize: '3em'}} `?

Comment: Just tried that works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you provide, they have an example

> ```
> <i class="pi pi-check" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
> ```

Just add `fontSize: 3em` (or the size you want).

```
<Button 
  label="" 
  icon="pi pi-cog"   
  className="cogIcon"  
  onClick={(e) => this.setState({visibleRight:true})} 
  style={{marginTop:'.25em', marginRight:'.25em', fontSize: '3em'} } 
/>
```

Comment: Ok, this works! although it won't let me change the border properties in this inline style object.